# What to do when child theme is out of date with parent theme

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, genesis-theme-framework

I inherited a site with Genesis as the parent theme and a Genesis child theme. The parent theme has smoothly been upgraded over the years.

The child theme, however, was based on an older version of Genesis. So it seems like there is an incompatibility between the child theme talking to the parent. e.g. the responsive style does not exists. I've run vimdiff between the child-theme/style.css and genesis/style.css and That's why I think they are not fully compatible.

So I guess my question is what should my next steps be? I cannot differentiate between the core child theme styles and the custom styles written by the site maintainer before me.

- The Wordpress UI tells me Genesis is at version 2.2.5
- The genesis/style.css file tells me it's version 2.1.2
- And my child theme says `Template: genesis` `Template Version: 1.7.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So honestly, I think this is just my fault. I was under the impression that a child theme extended the parent similar to how it works in drupal. It seems like the parent theme here has little to do with the display and more about framework type stuff, seo.

Comment: What is your question here? Please check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Genesis myself, but is there upgrade documentation? Similar to when Bootstrap gets updated between major releases, they change the class names but with some work you can re-connect them.

http://getbootstrap.com/migration/

Also, how extensive is the child theme? Can you remake it without driving yourself crazy?